# No more Automate Desktop support in IE Mode in Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, ui-automation, power-automate-desktop

So!

After getting a nice little Power Automate Desktop automation working on an IE site in IE Mode in Edge.  It seem that as of October 31st and in timing with the whole Microsoft 365 Dynamics move, it now no longer is supported.

I can’t find any word of this and deep down I’m hoping I’m just missing a subtle trick and need to change a setting.

Anyone else experiencing loss of automation of IE sites in IE Mode?

Protected Mode is off but the extension is greyed out only on IE Mode sites :-

Comment: ...why are you using IE Mode _at all_?

Comment: Mine works fine in IE mode (using the example of `Get metadata of a web page` in IE mode page). You can share an example of yours with us to reproduce the issue.